# Given the angles between the edges of a triangular pyramid, what is the angle between any one edge and it's opposing side?

Tags: geometry

[Rendition in paint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xHMy.png)

You have a triangular pyramid with the edges a, b, and c.
You know the angles between those edges - alpha (between a & c), beta (between b & c), and gamma (between a & b).
I hope I am also right in assuming that a plane can be formed by any of the two edges.
So what I'm looking for is the angle between an edge and the plane that is formed by the other edges.

As far as I can see, it's all pretty basic geometry, but after multiple hours and a few sheets of paper, I am probably approaching it the wrong way, and making some mistakes somewhere.
I don't think it would be of any help, but I can include a long description of one of my example solutions, which yielded an incorrect answer.

Comment: I think that a solution for $\theta_a$, the angle from edge a and plane containing b and C could be: $ \sin\theta_a =\sqrt{(1+\sin\beta /\sin\alpha+ \sin\gamma /\sin\alpha) (-1+\sin\beta /\sin\alpha+ \sin\gamma /\sin\alpha) (1-\sin\beta /\sin\alpha+ \sin\gamma /\sin\alpha) (1+\sin\beta /\sin\alpha- \sin\gamma /\sin\alpha)}$

Comment: That doesn't seem correct. For something like $\alpha = \beta = \gamma = \frac{\pi}{2}$, $\sin θ_a = \sqrt3$, which... isn't correct? Also the answer would be the same for any $\alpha = \beta = \gamma$, but as the angles get smaller, surely so does the answer.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that an **edge** is basically a straight line?

Comment: edge - the line along which two surfaces of a solid meet.

Comment: I'm sorry... while copying the equation I forgot that my angles are half yours, so, instead of $\alpha$ read $\alpha/2$ and so on. $\theta$ is not halved.

Comment: But that wouldn't change the result if $\alpha = \beta = \gamma$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Draw a triangular pyramid. $ABCD$ such that $\angle{BAC}=\beta,\angle CAD=\alpha$ and $\angle BAD=\gamma$. Drop a perpendicular from $C$ to $BD$ at point $E$.
>
> > First check  that $\angle CAE$ is your required angle.

Without loss of generality, we can make $AB=AC=AD=1$ unit.

Applying sine rule:$${BC\over \sin \beta}={1\over\cos(\beta/2)}$$So you know $BC$. Similarly you also know $CD\ \&\ BD$$${CD\over \sin\alpha}={1\over\cos(\alpha/2)}\ \ \ \ \&\ \ \ {BD\over\sin\gamma}={1\over \cos(\gamma/2)}$$

Now in $\Delta BCD,$ $$BC^2-BE^2=CD^2-(BD-BE)^2$$ You get $BE$, and hence $CE$.

> Check that the only thing to find is $AE$, because once you get that , you get $AE,AC\ \&\ CE$ and hence the entire triangle $ACE$ and hence $\angle CAE$.

Finding $AE$ is easy:

In triangle $ABD$, $\angle BAD=\gamma,\angle ABD=90^\circ -\gamma/2$.

As we know $BE\ \&\ DE$ , let $\angle BAE=x$ . Applying sine rule ,$${BE\over \sin x}={1\over \sin\angle AEB}={1\over \sin(180-\angle AEB)}={1\over \sin \angle AED}={ED\over \sin(\gamma-x)}$$
Find out $x$ and then apply $${BE\over \sin x}={AE\over \cos(\gamma/2)}$$

BINGO!!

Comment: @Torn : I know this is too much informal, but still: May I get an upvote?

Comment: I was simply not at 15 reputation at that point. =) I was planning to comment once I replaced everything into a single formula for myself, but stuff came up. Since the result is not dependent on the length of AB, AC, and AD, it should be possible to remove them from the final equation and leave only the three angles. I just hope I don't screw up somewhere again.

Comment: @Torn Of course. (Remembering the fact that a triangle with sides 1,2,3 has the same set of angles as a triangle with sides k,2k,3k)If you take the lengths to be $k$ units(instead of $1$ unit), then all lengths will come as $\alpha k: \alpha\in \Bbb{R}^+$. But this wont affect the angles..